# Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling Lambda dotnet6 Compatibility

Tags: c#, lambda, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have to create a CrmServiceClient object to perform crud operations on Crm Dynamics in a C# Lambda Function. I have this issue :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.CreateCRMWebServiceConnection

I think it's related to the compatibilty of the Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmToling.CoreAssembly API with my dotnet6 Lambda Function.
Is there any other compatible Xrm Api Tool to use in my Lambda.

Comment: Note : I have a warning in Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmToling.CoreAssembly (latest version 9.1.1.1) NuGet Package saying it's not completely compatible with my net6.0 Lambda Project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

supported .net framework with Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmToling.CoreAssembly is 4.6.2
you can use [.netcore assembly for dynamics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) if you want

[Announcing the .net Core SDK for Common Data Service (CDS) - External Client Development](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Announcing-the-net-Core-SDK-for-Common-Data-Service-CDS-External/td-p/470035)

Comment: Yes the .netcore assembly solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: could you please mark it as solved, will help me as well :)

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: Yess, How do i mark it as solved ?